# The best lightweight window manager for linux?

Tags: linux, window-manager

What is the best lightweight window manager  (optimized for running over a network) for Linux?

Answer (score 7):

Why do you wan't to run the windowmanager/desktop over the network? 
Is it not enough to run the application you are interested in with something like ssh and x-forwarding?

Beside that, how about xfce?

Comment: Run ssh with compression enabled to possibly further decrease the badnwidth cost.

Answer (score 5):

[Fluxbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluxbox) is a pretty good window manager if you want something very lightweight.

However, as Johan said, you should consider using ssh with x forwarding before you decide you need a graphical desktop.

Answer (score 4):

How about [Enlightenment](http://www.enlightenment.org/p.php?p=about/e16/) - it's lightweight, and still has a bit of eye candy ;)

[image: screenshot]

You can install it on Debian/Ubuntu by using `apt-get install e16`.

If you're running over a network, I would just use the "failsafe xterm" mode of your desktop manager.

Comment: The link you posted goes to version 17; your instructions (and snapshot) are for version 16.

Answer (score 2):

I've used dwm. It's very, very small and lightweight, but it's a dynamically tiling wm, so it takes a lot of getting used to.

Answer (score 2):

Openbox, but over a network I would use NX from nomachine

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run as an X terminal, there are many variants of [FVWM](http://www.fvwm.org/) that are fairly light on bandwidth.  If you want to run on a low spec PC, 'lightweight' window managers are two a penny.  I've used [IceWM](http://www.icewm.org/) on Vector Linux at one point and found it to be quite usable on a late model Pentium III.  You could probably use it on lower spec machines down to maybe 64 or 128MB of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

[WindowMaker](http://www.windowmaker.info/), giving all its sense to "lightweight".
(The only window manager which makes me think the system hanged because it loads in 1 second...)

Comment: Yeah, +1 for this. I used to use wmaker principally, but switched over to KDE at some point. Shame that the development has all but died out... but it apparently might make a comeback: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_Maker#History

Answer (score 1):

You should use any Window Manager you want at the remote host.

Maybe you want to take a look at [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) and [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/) for remote control software that performs reasonably well over broadband connections.

I recommend also enabling compression and X11 Forwarding through SSH if you decide to use only a lightweight window manager.

> user@yourmachine $ ssh -XC remoteuseruser@remotemachine
>
> remotemachine $ xclock &

Answer (score 1):

`screen` is about the only (sort of) window manager I'd use over SSH, but this only works for command-line tools.

For using GUI applications remotely, most of the time you don't need to run a window manager on the remote machine - just use X11 forwarding, to forward the specific application.

By default it should be enabled when you `ssh`, but you can enable it with the `ssh -X` (upper-case `X`) flag:

```
ssh -X example.net
```

If you have an X-server running locally, simply execute the command, say `firefox`, and it will magically appear on your local machine (although the process will be running remotely)

You need to be running an X server locally for this, on Linux this isn't a problem. On Windows [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) is good. On OS X, `X11.app` can be installed from your OS Installation disc, or from the ["X11 for Mac OS X 1.0" Apple download page](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/apple/macosx_updates/x11formacosx.html)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above re: using ssh with x forwarding.  However, regarding a light weight WM, I personally prefer tiling WMs such as awesome, dwm, xmonad, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Back around the days when I first ran Linux on a 486sx with 16MB (or it might have been 8MB) of RAM, and X paged when loading more than a very basic text editor or CD audio player, the window managers I used were OpenLook, FVWM, and IceWM.  OpenLook in particular was both nice (in an unusual, unique, but elegant sort of way) and lightweight too.  IceWM is a good lightweight option if you're looking for a windows-like feel.  FVWM would be great if you want the classic Unix workstation look on a tiny netbook :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest [Ratpoison](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/): I became addicted to it after a couple of hours using it. If you are a GNU Screen user you'll feel like at home, and it is surely the lighter window manager I used so far (in the list there are gnome, kde, lxde, enlightenment, fluxbox, openbox, xfce, icewm, fvwm, twm, and maybe others that I cannot remember).